# Python Telegram Bot Markdown

Tags: python, python-3.x, markdown, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am working on a Telegram Bot in Python but I struggle to use markdown correctly and I can not find any proper resources about the telegram markdown implementation. It gets even more complicated because of two different markdown "versions" (Markdown and Markdown_V2). And none of them is matching the behavior of the normal chat field (typing by hand).

Test String:

```
*Bold*, _italic_, *_bold and italic_*, **double bold**, __double italic__, __**double bold and double italic**__
```

`parse_mode="Markdown"`:

**Bold**, *italic*, **_bold and italic_**, double bold, double italic, double bold and double italic

`parse_mode="Markdown V2"`:

**Bold**, *italic*, **bold and italic**, double bold, double italic, double bold and double italic

in **Chat**:

*Bold*, _italic_, **bold and italic**, **double bold**, *double italic*, ***double bold and double italic***

-

How do I add bold **and** italic, and are there any other commands like underline and more? I need some explanation. Thanks.

Comment: That's not Markdown. In Markdown, `*this*` is italic, not bold, and `__this__` is bold, not "double italic", whatever that means.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Bots need a different markdown syntax.

To send bold and italic text use:

```
update.message.reply_text('*_bold and italic_*', parse_mode='MarkdownV2')
```

from the official telegram website https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style

````
*bold \*text*
_italic \*text_
__underline__
~strikethrough~
*bold _italic bold ~italic bold strikethrough~ __underline italic bold___ bold*
[inline URL](http://www.example.com/)
[inline mention of a user](tg://user?id=123456789)
`inline fixed-width code`
```
pre-formatted fixed-width code block
```
```python
pre-formatted fixed-width code block written in the Python programming language
```
````

I recommend to use only MarkdownV2 syntax, since Markdown is less powerful

Comment: "a different markdown syntax"—the markup shown in this question isn't Markdown. If you change something fundamental like what `*this*` means, you have a different language.

Comment: Actually telegram web does not show the combination, while the app does. Confused me even more ..., but now I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just a note, with Markdownv2 you have to escape special characters. "Special" here means those that Telegram defined as special ([doc](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#markdownv2-style)).

Personally I find it easier to work with `parse_mode='HTML'` where you can use a common function to escape HTML chars (e.g. `html.escape` in Python, `_.escape` in JS). With HTML you have way more options for text decoration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and the docs link. Read the docs. Got confused even more. Decided to use HTML parsing after all, as having to escape characters like '.' and '-' in V2 is just crazy.